# "man" can't find man page after installing Crunch Wordlist Generator on Fedora 25

Tags: linux, fedora, manpage, password-generator

```
[root@unknowna08cfd77f899 crunch-3.6]# ls
charset.lst  COPYING  crunch  crunch.1  crunch.c  Makefile                unicode_test.lst
[root@unknowna08cfd77f899 crunch-3.6]# make
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
[root@unknowna08cfd77f899 crunch-3.6]# man crunch
No manual entry for crunch
```

Any suggestions would be great because I am stuck in my tutorial.  Why is there no manual file?

Comment: try to copy manually crunch.1 into /usr/share/man/man1/.

Comment: ... Or read on-line http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/crunch.1.html ... I.e. almost every man page can be found with key word = man [app name]

Comment: Isn't this missing a `sudo make install`? I don't think you've actually installed it quite yet. Just compiled.

Comment: Thank you very much, can't believe I forgot to make install lol

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open locally built manual page that is not in the common path, you should use the `./` prefix, such as

```
man ./crunch.1
```

Answer (score 1):

> Resolved in comment:
>
> Isn't this missing a sudo make install?
>   I don't think you've actually installed it quite yet. Just compiled. – Benjamin W.